# sscanf() repeating value twice

Tags: c, scanf

When I am running the program, it seems that the `sscanf` is storing values to `val` twice. I don't know how to fix it.

// This is my array.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calculate.h"

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{   
    int intArray[SIZE];
    char* sArray[SIZE] = {"16", "2", "6", "9", "4", "13", "1", "27", "5"};  

    printf("Char Array to Int Array\n");
    formatter(*sArray, intArray, size);

    return 0;
}
```

/* This is my calculate.h file */

```
void formatter(char* sArray, int* intArray, int size).
#define SIZE 10
```

/*                              */

// From here calculate.c file//

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "calculate.h"

void formatter(char* sArray, int* intArray, int size)
{
    int i, val;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sscanf(sArray + i, " %d\n", &val);
        printf("Val = %d\n", val);
        intArray[i] = val; 
        printf("%d\n", intArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void formatter(char* sArray, int* intArray, int size);` --> `void formatter(char* sArray[], int* intArray, int size);`, `sscanf(sArray + i, " %d\n", &val);` --> `    sscanf(sArray[i], " %d\n", &val);`,
`formatter(*sArray, intArray, size);` --> `formatter(sArray, intArray, 9);`

Comment: Why do you re`define` `SIZE`?

Comment: `" "` and `"\n"` in `sscanf(sArray + i, " %d\n", &val);` serve no purpose - can drop those 2 `char`.  Or just use `strtol()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is crucial that argument data types match in *function definition* and *function call*. Let's slightly simplify the code for making the answer clear and self-explanatory:

```
#define SIZE 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void formatter(char* sArray[], int intArray[], int size) //argument data types in definition
{
    int i, val;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sscanf(sArray[i], "%d", &val);
    printf("Val = %d\n", val); //only for debugging, one can read directly into &intArray[i]
    intArray[i] = val; 
    printf("%d\n", intArray[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    int intArray[SIZE];
    char* sArray[SIZE] = {"16", "2", "6", "9", "4", "13", "1", "27", "5"};//member missing
    printf("Char Array to Int Array\n");
    formatter(sArray, intArray, SIZE - 1); //argument data types in call
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing at my accidental typo - fixed! Elsewhere I just wanted to stay as close to OP's code as valid.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of `formatter` should be `char *sArray[]`, then reading should be `sscanf(sArray[i],"%d",&val);` (forget `\n`). And `var` is not useful as you can write directly to it: `sscanf(sArray[i],"%d",intArray+i);`.

----EDIT----

Two fixes:

First you need to pass `sArray` at the call:

```
formatter(sArray, intArray, SIZE);
```

Second, you declared `SIZE` to be 10, but fill the array with only 9 values, add one more:

```
char* sArray[SIZE] = {"16", "2", "6", "9", "4", "13", "1", "27", "5" ,"666"};
```

Comment: So now it is compiling but I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when running the program.

Comment: Thanks Jean. Working now :)

Answer (score 0):

First argument in call to formatter should be sArray, not *sArray (assuming you fixed the argument list for formatter as suggested by @Jean-Baptiste Yunès )